# How can I extend a class in Python curses module

Tags: class, python-3.x, oop, curses, python-curses

In Python curses, a new window object can be created with the `curses.newwin()` function. How can I extend the class of the objects that are instantiated from the `newwin` function?

I have tried `dir(curses)` but couldn't find any obvious class names there for me to extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curses.newwin` returns a extension type.

Unfortunately, you can't set attributes of extension types.

As a workaround, you can redefine `curses.newwin` to return a new class instance that wraps the return value of the original `curses.newwin(..)`:

```
orig_newwin = curses.newwin
def newwin(*args):
    win = orig_newwin(*args)
    return Wrapper(win)
curses.newwin = newwin
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea although that doesn't look like it's redefining `curses.newwin`, and shouldn't you be relaying the *args ?

Comment: @HolyMackerel, Sorry, I missed the last line. just update the answer to include the line and to relay `*args`.